# FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPublishPermissions always returns result,isCancelled=YES on iOS 13.0

Tags: objective-c, facebook-login, ios13, xcode11, fbsdkloginkit

I am having trouble with login with facebook after updating to iOS 13.0. Recently I updated my xCode to 11.0 and my Device to 13.0. After the updation Login with facebook is not working. Always returns result.isCancelled = YES. Have checked everything on the internet but Not able to solve the issue. Code is below.

Login Button Action

```
[login logInWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]....
```

AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];



        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

And I am using Facebook SDK 5.3.0. Please help me to resolve this.